# I am trying to generate code verifier and code challenges in jMeter

Tags: encryption, oauth-2.0, jmeter, correlation, rs256

I am trying to generate code verifier and code challenges in JMeter for that I written a code

[image]

But it is not working. please help me to fix this

I want to generate a string for code verifier and code challenge and pass it too as a variable in my http request.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Your question does not contain an actual question. "It is not working" is not a reasonable problem statement. Your question's tags are, most likely, way off the actual problem, e.g. any relation to OAuth 2.0 is just totally unclear.

Comment: On the other hand, you can edit your question to improve it. Like adding a (formatted) copy of the error message you get (if that's what yo mean by "not work"), or describe what you observed as opposed to what you have expected. Also the SO concept suggests to copy and paste code as (formatted) text rather than a screenshot image (for web-search-ability).

Answer (score 0):

The code you "wrote" is working fine, double check your `dc_verifier` value using [Debug Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and you will see it's there

[image]

More information:

- [Authorization Request](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/pkce/authorization-request/)
- [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-templates)